# Cannot start rails app on nginx with passenger and https under WSL - port in use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, passenger, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to setup my development environment (coming from macOS) on WSL and Ubuntu.

The stack is as follows:
MySQL,
Ruby on Rails,
nginx,
passenger

The rails server runs fine on it's own as well as the already populated mysql db. Now when trying to open up a connection the follow error appears:

`` Address already in use - listen(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:303:in `listen'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:303:in `block in create_unix_socket_on_filesystem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:65:in `block in retry_at_most'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:63:in `times'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:63:in `retry_at_most'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:299:in `create_unix_socket_on_filesystem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:101:in `initialize'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:135:in `new'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:135:in `negotiate_spawn_command'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>' ``

I've already tried to close all Windows apps that could possibly occupy the ports (80 and 443) and checked via `netstat` but still it won't work.

Has anyone an idea what could possibly block the port or may be it's an issue within the communication between WSL/Ubuntu and Windows? Also hints on where to dig deeper / investigate further are welcome.

Comment: You will get a similar error if you don't have permission to use the port. Ports 80 and 443 are reserved for system use. You can only use them under `sudo`

Comment: P.S. it's likely upper nginx is using port 80, which would prevent passenger from using the same port(s). You should set the Rails application to a different port (it's common to use 3000 or 9292) and than forward the requests through nginx to the port you chose. On cloud hosting environments (i.e. Heroku), the port is dynamically assigned to the environment's `PORT` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a passenger issue when running in WSL.  By looking in the stack trace location (request_handler.rb), I noticed there is a way to work around this by forcing passenger not to use unix sockets and using TCP sockets instead. This worked for me in Apache:

Apache - in your config:

```
SetEnv _PASSENGER_FORCE_HTTP_SESSION true
```

nginx - in your config (untested but should work the same):

```
env _PASSENGER_FORCE_HTTP_SESSION=true;
```

passenger via command line:

```
_PASSENGER_FORCE_HTTP_SESSION=true passenger start ...
```

EDIT: Although this works for basic site request it seems to get stuck on ajax post requests so I'm still looking for a better workaround.

EDIT 2: The above has unintended side effects - I've done a proper fix and [sent a pull request to passenger](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/pull/2037).  In the meantime you could edit your passenger gem file to add this change to your local setup.